# Appendix on multiple pages: add the title "(Continued)"

Tags: appendices

I have realized a Latex document that holds two appendices. They are both included as .tex files.

The first appendix, **APPENDIX A**, is one page long (and it is fine). 
The second, **APPENDIX B**, is several pages long and I need on each of the pages after the first one to insert a title stating: **APPENDIX B (Continued)**.

Unfortunately, Latex only puts the APPENDIX B title on the first page of this second appendix but on the remaining ones there is no title.
I have tried to play with the `\appendix` command but I couldn't figure out a viable solution. Do you have any idea?
Thank you in advance!

Paolo

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We realized, that you provided no example which could give us a starter ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I used the `article` class and faked the inclusion of the appendix sections/chapters by directly writting them into the main file. The second appendix got some label, which is referred to using the `\fancyhead` command from `fancyhdr` package. The definition of a `apppages` (appendix pages) style is quite useful here. Afterwards, the pagestyle is switched back to `plain`

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\fancypagestyle{apppages}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\appendixname~\ref{appendix::b} (continued)}
}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\blindtext[50]

\appendix
\section{First appendix}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{apppages}
\section{Second appendix} \label{appendix::b} 
\blindtext[20]
\clearpage % Clear the page 
\pagestyle{plain}
\section{Other appendix}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]